# How to convert a string with multiple points to double in android

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, numberformatexception

I have a string "3,350,800" with multiple points I want to convert to double but have error **multiple points**

```
String number = "3,350,800"
number = number.replace(",", ".");
double value = Double.parseDouble(number);
```

> Error : java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points

Comment: Are you wanting to parse it as a double with a decimal place, or as an integer? Which comma are you expecting to be a decimal place if you want a double?

Comment: A number cannot have multiple decimal points. So it is not possible to parse it as `double`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.` character is used as a decimal point in English, and you cannot have more than one of those in a number.

It seems like you're using it as a thousands separator though. This is legal in several locales - you just need to use one that allows it, e.g.:

```
String number = "3.350.800";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
double value = format.parse(number).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Mix of other answers, no reason to change the , for . and then fetch the German local.

```
String number = "3,350,800";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
double value = format.parse(number).doubleValue();
System.out.println(value);
```

Output:

```
3350800.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use something like this :

```
String number = "3,350,800";
number = number.replaceAll(",", "");
double value = Double.parseDouble(number);
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score -1):

What number are you trying to get?
`3.350.800` is what you're trying to parse as a double,
but that's obviously not a number, since there are "multiple points".

If you just wanna get `3,350,800` as your number, simply change this line -
`number = number.replace(",", ".");`

to this -
`number = number.replace(",", "");`